# Why is Michael Burry's assistant shown working at a convenience store stocking Red Bull?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-big-short

In *The Big Short*, Michael Burry has a recurring assistant character throughout the movie. As his firm continues to lose money, the staff dwindles until only the assistant character is left. He asks Michael Burry why he is wrong.

Later, once Michael Burry is successful, you see the assistant in a convenience store stocking Red Bull (you can see the [clip here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlbG6G_iHLU&t=28s)). My question, is why does he end up in this position? What inference are we supposed to have made? I seriously cannot figure it out. Is it implied he lost faith in Michael Burry and quit?

Answer (score 3):

Scion's closing impacted many people.  During that clip you see one guy stocking shelves, one guy looks to be living out of his car, another couple of people at a job fair trying to find employment.  This is the "big picture" of the closure of a business.  It's one thing to say, "Scion closed it's doors today", it's another thing to show you how that actually impacted the people who worked there.

Answer (score 1):

This scene is part of a montage that plays out while Michael Burry announces that Scion Capital is closing down (as stated in the title of the linked YouTube video). The inference seems fairly clear to me: with Scion Capital having closed down, the assistant has lost his job, and has had to find alternative employment.

Comment: I guess what confuses me is that Michael Burry is extremely successful at this point, but doesn't help his loyal assistant?